# IE11 renders elements with border-radius incorrectly

Tags: windows-8.1, css, internet-explorer-11

My Internet Explorer 11.0.13 renders all css-elements with a positive border-radius incorrectly: it shows diagonal lines and shaded areas over the component, at times making it illegible. This happens on all pages. If I set the border-radius to 0 for these elements, they are rendered correctly. Here is a screenshot that shows the problem on Google's home page.

[image]

I turned off GPU rendering, but that did not solve the problem. Can anyone suggest other solutions, or at least tell me what this phenomenon is called, so that I can search for it?

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro on an HP 840G.

Added 10 January 2015:

Here's a small example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><style>
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<div style="border-radius:0px"></div><br>
<div style="border-radius:5px"></div><br>
<div style="border-radius:10px"></div><br>
<div style="border-radius:25px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This renders as follows:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting IE through "Internet Options"?

Comment: Please post your html & css. You could also try the workarounds in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810546/internet-explorer-11-blur-background-image-with-border-radius).

Comment: @roelandvanbeek: You could try resetting your Windows theme in case it is corrupt since it is possible for it to cause glitches in IE.

Comment: Does this also happen if you log in in Safe Mode (with Networking)? How about if you log into Normal Mode as a different user? Have you ensured your video drivers are up-to-date with the latest available version?

Comment: I know this might be less than ideal, but have you considered trying another browser to see if it behaves differently?

Comment: Does this happen in other programs or just IE? Try running a video card test and see if it appears then too.  You need to narrow it down if it is app specific or something else.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: yes, also happens in safe mode, also as a different user. Video drivers are up to date.

Comment: @EricF: I wish I knew how to narrow it down - if only someone could tell me how to describe this issue... Anyway, it doesn't happen in other browsers, only IE. It also happens in Skype in Metro interface, but I think the application runs on HTML5 and IE is rendering it.

Comment: What's your screen resolution set to? Is it correct for  your monitor? What colour depth is your desktop (15-Bit, 16-Bit, 24-Bit, 32-Bit)? What happens if you connect an external monitor to the laptop?

Comment: This is probably a bug in IE11, but analyzing it requires posting your html & css (as I requested above but without any response from you).

Comment: As my solution suggests, along with harrymc, it probably has to do with your css

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, I probably didn't make clear that this happens on any page, for any element with non-zero border-radius. Either way, as per your request, I also added an example to the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in IE11 that is is signaled several times in Microsoft Connect,
but it does not seem as if Microsoft understands it.

I have been able to restore the correct display by adding the following line to the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

This puts IE11 into IE10 compatibility mode, where border-radius is displayed correctly :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to point at something. But that means that I have to view all websites in compatibility mode?

Comment: Apparently so, until Microsoft fixes the bug. Or use another browser (which, given the number of security risks discovered each year in IE, is IMHO a better solution).

Comment: I'm using Chrome for most purposes, but because some Windows apps (such as Skype) are using IE, I don't have a choice for them. Do you happen to be able to point at a bug report?

Comment: Yes, for example [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/794878/ie11-border-radius-background-bug) and this [other one](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808920/ie11-renders-white-lines-when-border-radius-and-gradients-are-applied-to-buttons).

Answer (score 1):

Disabling IE11’s Compatibility View may help :

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or Setting (gear icon)
2. Choose `Compatibility View Settings`
3. Uncheck the `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View` checkbox
4. Restart IE11

For more details, see the article
[Fix: CSS border-radius not working in Internet Explorer 11](http://blog.jonschneider.com/2014/03/fix-css-border-radius-not-working-in.html).

Comment: Doesn't fix it, unfortunately.

Comment: Your question was from over a month ago. Have you updated since then and has that fixed it?

Comment: I've been having the issue for a year now, no updates have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache.

Go into IE and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

Then tick/untick the following boxes, as shown in the picture.

[image: Click this]

Then wait for it to delete all these files (it may take a minute or two) and when it is done, refresh the page.

Comment: Doesn't fix it. I think it's something more "elementary" than this, something related to rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is happening in Skype as well as IE I would take a look at your css settings since that runs many parts of Skype and possibly could be used on Google's webpage like you displayed.  If this doesn't solve it then I would test your video card in another computer to see if the same issue appears. If it does, then I would suspect the video card is bad.

From Skype's support page:

```
There are a few solutions to this problem. 
You can either revert your .css settings to the Windows default by applying a registry patch, patch the 
Skype local web page, or downgrade to Skype 6.9 or below.  Hopefully the problem will be addressed in a 
future release.


.css registy patch
http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-clie​nt/Skype-6-10-0-104-BIG-Login-screen-problem/m-p/2​...

-- or --

Skype local web page patch (location: the index.html @ %programdata%\Skype\Apps\login\)
http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-clie​nt/Skype-UI-issues-after-updating-to-6-10/m-p/2114​...
```

I know this is just for skype but if something is wrong with your css settings, it would affect your webpages too since many elements like buttons (as you showed) are rendered using css.

Hope this helps some!

Comment: Thanks, but this is abuot the Skype Desktop UI, I was talking about the Modern UI. The problem there is the same as in the examples in my question, not that the CSS is missing altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue in IE 11, Edge and Firefox 57.0 (64-bit), after upgrading Windows 8 to Windows 10. Ultimately updating the graphic card drivers fixed the issue.